# Flipping display & locking keyboard for 'transformer'-style laptops

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, laptop, tablet, toshiba-satellite

Is there a quick fix that'll bring the 'transformer' functionality back to my laptop?

When my Toshiba Satellite was running windows, the keyboard would lock up, and the display would flip itself upside-down. That way, I could set the laptop's keyboard-side on a table and use it as a tablet. Now, I have to use shortcuts to flip the screen, and there's no way to turn off the keyboard (if I set it down on the table, just about every key gets pressed all at once).

Please let me know if there's a patch or fix out there for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema josephgodoy wants to enable the same flipping display functionality as his Windows had in Ubuntu 16.04.